# How can I identify the crash from crash log (report) in Xcode Diagnostic Reporting?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, crash-reports, diagnostics

The mask in red are the places of my application name but I can't click any of the place to navigate to any line of my code. From those black ones I don't think I am able to get any useful information. From the grey hints, they all look like from system libraries. I have many users installed my application but it says like around 40 devices in the past two weeks crashed with this type of issue but I can't reproduce it and can't fix it neither.

Any help would be appreciate.. Thanks advanced.

[image: Crash report]

Comment: What does open in project button do for you?

Comment: It opens but not showing me which line of code. Just open it in Xcode. @kush